# How to install previous version of Aptana

Tags: aptana, aptana3

I don't like the 3.6 version at all. It has too many bugs and it's too slow compared with the previous versions, so I'd like to install to a previous version and wait till they fix the problems. I can't downgrade the installation, so no, not an option.

I know that in this web: https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Reverting+to+a+Previous+Version there is a list of old versions, but this are VERY old, I'd like to download at least the 3.4.2 version or newer (like 3.5), but I can't see any link from wich I can download it. Can anyone give me a link or way to get previous versions of aptana?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oh yes, oh yes, finally I found them:

MAC OS

http://d1iwq2e2xrohf.cloudfront.net/tools/studio/standalone/3.4.2.201308081805/mac/Aptana_Studio_3_Setup_3.4.2.dmg

WINDOWS

http://d1iwq2e2xrohf.cloudfront.net/tools/studio/standalone/3.4.2.201308081805/win/Aptana_Studio_3_Setup_3.4.2.exe

Linux 32 bits

http://d1iwq2e2xrohf.cloudfront.net/tools/studio/standalone/3.4.2.201308081805/linux/Aptana_Studio_3_Setup_Linux_x86_3.4.2.zip

Linux 64 bits

http://d1iwq2e2xrohf.cloudfront.net/tools/studio/standalone/3.4.2.201308081805/linux/Aptana_Studio_3_Setup_Linux_x86_64_3.4.2.zip

Can't get the plugin, sorry.

Comment: If anyone is interested here's a link to different versions of Aptana: http://sourceforge.net/projects/aptana.mirror/files/

Answer (score 1):

You could find Aptana 3.4.2 as Eclipse plugin at the following URL: http://d1iwq2e2xrohf.cloudfront.net/tools/studio/plugin/update/studio3/3.4.2.201308081736/com.aptana.feature.studio-3.4.2.201308081736-7W7I57boG98RAi489ctbvKi7VXbq.zip

When you are installing it from the zip, make sure you un-tick "Group Items by Category"